# Insert element into a double array

Tags: java, arrays, insert, double, element

I have a method, seemingly fine, for putting double values into a double array. It is

```
insert(int i, double value)
```

where i is the index (array[i]) and value is what I want in that index.

I split the method into edge cases, built in a sufficient safe block of initialized array space (length) and buffered that with a part of the method that doubles the length every time the number of elements is equal or greater than the length. I then put methods for when the input i is greater than the number of items (numItems) of the array and when it is less than numItems. i < numItems is working fine, but when I try to put in

```
insert(63,3)
insert(15,3)
insert(23,3)
```

into my `(1,-1,5,23)` array I only get 2 three's on the last part of my array. My initial array length is 10, so it's not a memory issue. I thought it might be a print method error and tried to obtain the last element manually, which told me the index was empty. Thus it is a logic error in my method, which follows.

```
// if i is greater than the number of items, insert value into numItems index,
// and not any farther. e.g. if i = 100000 and numItems = 10, put value into
// items[10] and not items[100000];
if (i > numItems) 
{
    items[numItems] = value; 
    numItems++; //add to counter
    return;
}
```

The thing is, it's such simple code that I can't tell what's wrong with it. Very intuitive, and very puzzling. Ideas?

below is the whole of the insert method

```
public void insert(int i, double value) //insert value into array[i]
{
    if(i < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("i < 0; please input i >= 0 for array indices."); //an array cannot have an indice < 0;
        return;
    }

    if (numItems >= items.length) // if the number of items becomes equal or greater than the array containing it
    {
        double[] tempItems = new double [items.length * 2]; // create a new array double the size of current
        for(int j =0 ; j < items.length; j++ ) //and copy all elements into the new array
        {
            tempItems[j] = items[j];
        }

        items = tempItems; //set the temp array as the main array.
    }

    if (i > numItems) //if i is greater than the number of items, insert value into numItems index, and not any farther.
    {                 // i.e. if i = 100000 and numItems = 10, put value into items[10] and not items[100000];
        items[numItems] = value; 
        numItems++; //add to counter
        return;
    }

    if ( i < numItems) //if i is inside the used boundaries of the array
    {
        for (int k = numItems; k > i; k--) //shift values over to the right.
        {   
            items[k]=items[k-1];
        }

        items[i] = value; //and insert value into i
        numItems++; //add to counter
        return;
    }


}
```

Comment: Please provide the defined section of the array after those three calls. (items[0] through items[6], if I understand your method correctly.)

Comment: 1.0
-1.0,
5.0,
23.0,
3.0,
3.0
and beyond that I get a 0.0, for which the array is initialized

Comment: Have you tested it using distinct double values? What was the result of this test? Is the value of numItems changed anywhere else?

Comment: yes, the value of numItems is changed with when a remove method removes an element, or in any other part of the insert method where it handles cases else(i>numItems). I'll edit to show more of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of any modifications that alter array size (insert or delete) it is recommended to use [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations. [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), for example. It saves you from headache with temporary arrays and moving of elements.

Also, to copy some elements from array to array you should consider using existing methods like [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) and various copying methods from [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Comment: the only thing is I'm trying not to use those... to try and implement stuff